# How can I add noise to a neural network input?

Tags: neural-networks

A common "trick" in neural network training is to train an autoencoder using a "degraded" sample as input and the original sample as target output. The layer type `DropoutLayer[]` is made for this purpose. But I would like to play with different types of noise, e.g. Gaussian noise, salt&pepper noise, to train a denoising autoencoder.

I can think of a few ways to implement this, but I'm not happy with any of them:

- I can add noise offline and pass the noisy and original samples to `NetTrain` as input and target, respectively. But then exactly the same noise trained in every round, which probably leads to overfitting.
- I can pass noisy samples to `NetTrain` as above, but only train a few rounds, then restart with different noisy samples. (i.e. call `NetTrain` in a loop). But that seems to break a lot of the internal learning-rate heuristics in `NetTrain` (e.g. the momentum term is reset in every cycle)
- I can link together a constant input, a several dropout layers and a `TotalLayer` to get a poor man's Gaussian noise approximation, (each `DropoutLayer` produces a Bernoulli random variable per pixel, and the sum of a number of Bernoulli random variables is approximately Gaussian). This is my best idea so far, but I need a lot of `DropoutLayer`s to get close to a continuous distribution, and it's not very efficient to include an input that's always constant

Comment: May be you can use "$AugmentationFunction" -> f for image NetEncoder... you can check the answers from this link as an idea but I don't think it's exactly what you need... http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126120/training-data-generator

Comment: @s.s.o: If this is called repeatedly for every round, it would be perfect, but I'll have to come up with some way to test this... Thanks for the link, that question is very similar and it's good to hear this will be addressed in 11.1

Comment: If I understand correctly you want every round different noise... In fact NN can accept file names (in order to keep the original images) you can add the argumentation function to this file name get random noised images and feed it to NN. Similar to Alexey Golyshev multi round training with Do[ ...  {numberOfRounds}] you can do multi stage training. Not best solution but may help.

Comment: Has anyone figured out the most efficient way to do this? I tried using the new generator function in 11.1, which allows NetTrain to create each batch of training data according to any given function. However, this slows down the training by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `` NeuralNetworks`NoiseLayer ``

```
<<NeuralNetworks`
noisy = NetGraph[{
    "noise" -> NoiseLayer[{3, 90, 160}, "Distribution" -> NormalDistribution[0, 0.1]],
    "add" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus]
},
    {{"noise", NetPort["Input"]} -> "add"},
    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {160, 90}}],
    "Output" -> NetDecoder["Image"]
]
```

You can find more undocumented definitions with

`` NeuralNetworks`$LayerData["Noise"]//Dataset ``

Comment: Hi, it seems like NoiseLayer is outdated. Do you know how to add the random noise for Mathematica v 11.3?

Answer (score 11):

For what it's worth, this is my "add binomial random variate layer":

```
Needs["NeuralNetworks`"] (* for ScalarTimesLayer, ScalarPlusLayer *)
With[{σ = 0.1, n = 5},
 addNoiseLayer = NetGraph[
   Flatten@{
     TotalLayer[], ScalarTimesLayer[σ*1./5], 
     ScalarPlusLayer[-1*σ], TotalLayer[],
     Table[DropoutLayer[], {n}]
     },
   Flatten@{
     1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4,
     NetPort["Input"] -> 4,

     Table[NetPort["const"] -> 4 + i -> 1, {i, n}]
     }, "Input" -> inputDim, "const" -> inputDim]]
```

[image]

Comment: mma says "ScalarTimesLayer[0.02] is not a net function.",and environment is ""11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)""

Comment: @partida: not tested, but I think you can use `ElementwiseLayer[#*0.02 &]` in version 11

Comment: yes,they do the same thing,thanks

Answer (score 5):

In Mathematica `12.1`, DropoutLayer exposes his mask, so it's possible to train using a random binary mask, with `DropoutLayer["OutputPorts" -> "BinaryMask"]` (or `DropoutLayer["OutputPorts" -> {"Output", "BinaryMask"}]`)
[image: Documentation of DropoutLayer (new in 12.1)]

In Mathematica `12.2`, it will be possible to simulate many types of noises (including once where you give the parameters -like mean and variance- through outputs of other subparts of a NetGraph).
The novelty is already documented in the current 12.2 builds under the name of `RandomArrayLayer`.
[image: Documentation of RandomArrayLayer (introduced 12.2)]
[image: Application of RandomArrayLayer (introduced 12.2)]
[image: Application of RandomArrayLayer (introduced 12.2)]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by using a generator function for generating network inputs during `NetTrain`. Here's a minimal (if somewhat nonsensical) example:

```
net = NetInitialize @ NetGraph[
   <|
    "chain" -> NetChain[{5, Ramp, 1}],
    "plus" -> ThreadingLayer[Plus]
    |>,
   {
    {NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Noise"]} -> "plus" -> "chain"
    },
   "Input" -> {1}
];

data = List /@ N[Range[10]];
genFun = Function[
   With[{dat = RandomChoice[data, #BatchSize]},
    <|
     "Input" -> dat,
     "Output" -> dat,
     "Noise" -> RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {#BatchSize, 1}]
     |>
    ]
];
```

Test the generator:

```
genFun[<|"BatchSize" -> 5|>]
```

> <|"Input" -> {{9.}, {3.}, {10.}, {5.}, {5.}}, "Output" -> {{9.}, {3.}, {10.}, {5.}, {5.}}, "Noise" -> {{0.605894}, {-1.57657}, {0.586584}, {-1.8153}, {0.443682}}|>

Train using the generator:

```
NetTrain[net, genFun]
```

Each round, `genFun` will be evaluated to create a new batch of training examples, so each round you'll get fresh random numbers.