# How to use Mathematica to train a network Using out of core classification?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I see there is doc about [how to train a network Using out of core image classification](http://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/out-of-core-image-classification.html) and this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126120/training-data-generator/126162#126162).But the object is only image.

I want to use a **binary** file as data(*Sequence to Sequence case*),for example like [this](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/test_data_SE.dat).

```
data = Flatten@Table[{x, y} -> x*y, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 1, .05}];
mydata = Flatten[data /. {(a_ -> b_) -> {a, b}}];
BinaryWrite[file, mydata, "Real32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
Close[file];
```

***Length of data:1681***

The data looks like this:

[image]

Usually,the size of data is very large,so it is only a example.

I use this code:

```
fileName = "C:\\Users\\xiaoz\\Downloads\\test_data_SE.dat"; 
file = OpenRead[fileName, BinaryFormat -> True]; 
net = NetChain[{32, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
size = FileByteCount[fileName];

read[file_, batchSize_] := If[StreamPosition[file] + 
 batchSize*3(*length of data in one batch*)*4(*float data*)> size,
 SetStreamPosition[file, 0]; BinaryReadList[file, "Real32", batchSize*3], 
 BinaryReadList[file, "Real32", batchSize*3]];

batchSize = 128;
Do[data = read[file, batchSize];
 trainingData = #[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]] & /@ Partition[data, 3];
 net = NetTrain[net, trainingData, BatchSize -> batchSize, 
 MaxTrainingRounds -> 1,TrainingProgressReporting -> None], {200}]

ContourPlot[net[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
Close[file]
```

[image]

You can see,it is slow and the result is not perfect with [image]

So how to use Mathematica to train a network Using out of core classification?

***Releated:*** I use *TensorFlow* can handle this Using Queue and Multi-thread:
[What's going on in tf.train.shuffle_batch and `tf.train.batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43028683/whats-going-on-in-tf-train-shuffle-batch-and-tf-train-batch/43190902#43190902)

And the wolfram blog says:

> Another thing that’s being introduced as an experiment in Version 11.3 is the MongoLink package, which supports connection to external MongoDB databases. We use MongoLink ourselves to manage terabyte-and-beyond datasets for things like machine learning training. And in fact MongoLink is part of our large-scale development effort—whose results will be seen in future versions—to seamlessly support extremely large amounts of externally stored data.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay here's how you do out-of-core training with HDF5:

```
input = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
output = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];

Get["GeneralUtilities`"];
ExportStructuredHDF5["test.h5", <|"Input" -> input, 
  "Output" -> output|>]

NetTrain[LinearLayer["Input" -> 2, "Output" -> 2], File["test.h5"]]
```

The use of `ExportStructuredHDF5` is just for convenience, you could also `Export` but it doesn't support associations directly. But again you'll need to make a dataset that consists of extendible columns if you want a real-world out-of-core example.

Also important to note is that you need to randomize the order of data yourself before writing it to the H5 file.

Comment: "...you need to randomize the order of data yourself..." - `RandomSample[]` ought to do the trick.

Comment: @J.M. True. But if it was small enough that you could fit it in memory (and  use RandomSample) then you probably wouldn't need to use an H5 file in the first place! H5 files can be useful for just holding training data, of course, but the main intended use is out-of-core learning.

Comment: but if the size of datast is large,shuffle it to a new dateset file will spend lots of time.Is there some way to handle it? I would have thought NetTrain can shffle dataset automaticaly.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon  Can we simply provide a bunch of h5 files as the training data? That should solve problems with having to use extendible columns

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Does it support `ValidationSet -> File["data.h5"]` yet?

Comment: @partida auto-shuffling would result in non-contiguous lookups which would be prohibitively slow. ValidationSet is not supported yet, sorry.

Comment: @dan7geo I think a good alternative is to support multiple datasets per column, e.g. "batchn/colname". That way you can use the existing Export to do things, because it allows appending onto an existing file.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon I think it would still be beneficial to support multiple large h5 files while training (maybe sample each batch by cycling through the files if that's efficient enough). This would be easier to organize and manage than one giant h5 file, for example when continuously generating and transferring datasets from different machines and when removing older data.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon when the net is `NetInitialize@
  NetChain[{BasicRecurrentLayer[5, "Input" -> {"Varying", 3}], 
    SequenceLastLayer[], 3}]`,I find it can't be used in h5 way because of the length of Input will vary

Answer (score 16):

There are two parts to your question: 1. How to use out-of-core classification and 2. Why is the result bad.

For the first part, you can use a generator to solve the problem. And for the second part, the reason for a bad result is because the data is not randomized.

```
fileName = "/Users/xslittlegrass/Downloads/test_data_SE.dat";

data = RandomSample@Flatten@Table[{x, y} -> x*y, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 1, .05}];
mydata = Flatten[data /. {(a_ -> b_) -> {a, b}}];
Close@BinaryWrite[fileName, mydata, "Real32", ByteOrdering -> -1];
```

Notice I use `RandomSample` to shuffle the data.

```
file = OpenRead[fileName, BinaryFormat -> True];
net = NetChain[{32, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
size = FileByteCount[fileName];
read[file_, batchSize_] := 
  If[StreamPosition[file] + 
     batchSize*3(*length of data in one batch*)*4(*float data*)> size,
    SetStreamPosition[file, 0]; 
   BinaryReadList[file, "Real32", batchSize*3], 
   BinaryReadList[file, "Real32", batchSize*3]];

batchSize = 128;
```

We can define a generator that reads the data from the file

```
generator = Function[#[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3]] & /@ Partition[read[file, #BatchSize], 3]];

net = NetTrain[net, generator, BatchSize -> 128, MaxTrainingRounds -> 1000]
Close[file];
```

The result looks much better now

```
ContourPlot[net[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I want to add sth that If the size of file is large and want to shuffle data.The read function can be modified to `read[file_, batchSize_] := 
  Table[SetStreamPosition[file, 
    RandomInteger[{0, size/(3*4) - 1}]*3*4]; 
   BinaryReadList[file, "Real32", 3], batchSize];`

Answer (score 15):

@xslittlegrass's answer is perfect, but I want to give a heads up that we will ship a way to stream training data to NetTrain from an ".h5" file that can be arbitrarily big (e.g. hundreds of gigabytes). This will hopefully ship in 11.1.1 or 11.2. The ".h5" file must have a (very simple format): one dataset for each port, so in your example an "Input" dataset and an "Output" dataset.

Unfortunately it will remain undocumented for now for the reason that our existing HDF5 exporter cannot create extendible datasets using the documented functionality, so it's hard for you to use Mathematica to *create* the out-of-core dataset in the first place. You could obviously create it in something else, like Python. But for some power users it will be just the ticket, and much faster than using BinaryRead + your own generator.

Comment: Amazing! What a big step forward in neutral networks of Mathematica.

Comment: An update: this made it into 11.1.1. I'll provide an example of how to use it once that ships.

Comment: 11.1.1 is release,where is the example?

Comment: Can you provide how to use Stream in NetTrain?

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon tell us, oh tell us please! ;)

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Can hardly wait......

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon please.....

Comment: Haha @partida sorry! See my answer below.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon wow.. Thank you..can't wait anymore

Answer (score 4):

Thank you @Taliesin Beynon.

And I write a python code to transform binary file to **hdf5** file.

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np
import struct
import random
float_size=4

input_node=2
output_node=1
input_file='test_data_SE.dat'
out_file='test_data_SE.h5'

input_and_output_node=input_node+output_node
with open(input_file,'rb') as f:
    f.seek(0,os.SEEK_END)
    file_len=f.tell()/(float_size*input_and_output_node)

with h5py.File(out_file, "w") as f:
    Input =  f.create_dataset('Input',  (1681,input_node ),dtype='float', chunks=True)
    Output = f.create_dataset('Output', (1681,output_node),dtype='float', chunks=True)
    fin=open(input_file,'rb')
    index=range(file_len)
    random.shuffle(index)
    for i in index:
        Input[i]  = np.array(struct.unpack('<'+str(input_node )+'f',fin.read(float_size*input_node)))
        Output[i] = np.array(struct.unpack('<'+str(output_node)+'f',fin.read(float_size*output_node)))
    fin.close()
```

Then import data to `Mathematica`, you can view the data:

[image]

```
net = NetChain[{32, Tanh, 1}, "Input" -> 2, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
net = NetTrain[net, File["test_data_SE.h5"],ValidationSet -> Scaled[0.2]]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[net[{x, y}], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> "RedGreenSplit", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
(*well done!*)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with h5py, but it could be because you are using chunks that are too granular. In fact isn't your chunk-size 1 here? You should use a bigger size, some multiple of the batch size, like 1024 or something.