# How to export nontrivial data to h5?

Tags: export, import, data, image, hdf5-format

Version 11.1.1 comes with improved support for the HDFv5 (HDF is an acronym for Hierarchical Data Format) file format. **How can I export (and import) the following data into h5 format?**

The data I want to export contains both images and lists of lists, here's a minified example:

```
imgs = ExampleData /@ RandomChoice[ExampleData["TestImage"], 10];
faces = FindFaces /@ imgs;
dummy = <|"images" -> imgs, "faces" -> faces|>
Export["micro-face-dataset.h5", dummy]
```

[image]

Furthermore, *I need the data to be written in a standard way* so I can access it not only like

```
Import["micro-face-dataset.h5", {"Datasets", {"/images"}}]
```

but also from other languages, e.g. python's h5py:

```
f = h5py.File('micro-face-dataset.h5', 'r') 
dataset = f['/images']
```

Here's a list of subproblems that make this processes tricky:

- How can we specify attributes and formats for mixed data types (and encode the images properly, etc.) for export? The docs show examples for import only:
  [image]
- How can we export/import ragged lists?
  [image]

**Update**

@yode This is definitely possible, see ExampleData/image.h5, one can load it into python:

```
>>> import h5py, numpy as np
... f = h5py.File('image.h5','r')
... img = np.array(f['image24bitpixel'])
... print img.shape
(149, 227, 3)
```

It's just a question of how it was created, perhaps with `ExportStructuredHDF5[]` in GeneralUtilities.

Comment: Hard to say,I think it is impossible as my test.

Comment: [Taliesin's comment on h5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143186/1364) maybe useful to look at.

Comment: His comment is more of a teaser trailer

Answer (score 7):

This way can export the data

```
imgs = ExampleData /@ RandomChoice[ExampleData["TestImage"], 10];
faces = FindFaces /@ imgs;
dummy = <|"images" -> imgs, "faces" -> faces|>;

Get["GeneralUtilities`"];
ExportStructuredHDF5["micro-face-dataset.h5", 
    <|"images" -> ImageData /@ imgs, "faces" -> faces|>]
```

Import the data from file

```
Import["micro-face-dataset.h5", {"Data", "faces"}]

Image /@ Import["micro-face-dataset.h5", {"Data", "images"}]
```

[image]

Comment: But the `ImportStructuredHDF5` don't work,so how do you import the file?

Comment: @yode see my answer, I modify it

Comment: I'm sorry,I find the `ImportStructuredHDF5` work well,but it will fail if the path have some *non-ASCII characters*..

Comment: @yode I don't know what the right way,but this can work`importhdf5[file_] := 
  Reap[RenameFile[file, "test_NonASCII.h5", OverwriteTarget -> True]; 
    Sow[Image /@ Import["micro-face-dataset.h5", {"Data", "images"}]];
    RenameFile["test_NonASCII.h5", file, OverwriteTarget -> True]][[2,
     1]];     importhdf5["测试.h5"]`

Comment: Of you can solve the problem when just the `.h5` file name have those character.But I am tend to think this this bug. if your path(not only in your file name,but also in your middle **directory**) have *non-ASCII* charater(such as *Chinese character*),then you will fail to import.

Comment: @yode    emmm.......  yes, and the `RunProcess` don't support non-ascii well.I also encounter this many times before         (；′⌒`)