# How to train Sequence-to-sequence autoencoder using LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

According [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html),I find the Seq2Seq auto-encoder.
But it didn't give any example only code.

[image]

> To build a LSTM-based autoencoder, first use a LSTM encoder to turn your input sequences into a single vector that contains information about the entire sequence, then repeat this vector n times (where n is the number of timesteps in the output sequence), and run a LSTM decoder to turn this constant sequence into the target sequence.

So I try to make similar thing in Mathematica using MNIST database.

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
testData = ResourceData[resource, "TestData"];
trainingSubset = Select[trainingData, Last[#] <= 4 &];
testSubset = Select[testData, Last[#] <= 4 &];
trainingImages = Keys[trainingSubset];
meanImage = Image[Mean@Map[ImageData, trainingImages]];
```

This is normal DNN auto-encoder of MNIST.

```
encoder = NetChain[{FlattenLayer[], 100, Ramp, 50, Ramp, 16}];
decoder = NetChain[{32, 50, Ramp, 100, Ramp, 784, ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
net = NetGraph[{encoder, decoder, MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Output"], 2 -> NetPort[3, "Input"], NetPort["Input"] -> NetPort[3, "Target"]}, 
               "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale", "MeanImage" -> meanImage}], 
               "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", "Grayscale"}]]
{lossplot1, trained} = NetTrain[net, <|"Input" -> trainingImages|>, "Loss", 
                                {"LossEvolutionPlot", "TrainedNet"}, 
                                BatchSize -> 256, MaxTrainingRounds -> 10];
```

[image]

We could explore the visulization of it.

```
reconstructor = Take[trained, {NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Output"]}];
BlockRandom[
 Grid[{#, ImageAdd[reconstructor[#], meanImage] & /@ #} &@
   RandomSample[trainingImages, 10]], RandomSeeding -> 1234]
```

[image]

```
encoder = Take[trained, {NetPort["Input"], 1}];
testImages = Keys[testSubset];
coords = DimensionReduce[encoder[testImages], 2, Method -> "TSNE"];
labels = Values[testSubset];
ListPlot[Table[Extract[coords, Position[labels, i]], {i, 0, 4}], 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[96, Range[0, 4]], Axes -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[96], Range[1, 5]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

But using autoencoder based LSTM,the result isn't good.

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
                    SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
net = NetGraph[{encoder, decoder, MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Output"], 2 -> NetPort[3, "Input"], NetPort["Input"] -> NetPort[3, "Target"]}, 
                "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale", "MeanImage" -> meanImage}], 
                "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", "Grayscale"}]]
{lossplot2, trained} = NetTrain[net, <|"Input" -> trainingImages|>, "Loss", 
                                {"LossEvolutionPlot", "TrainedNet"}, 
                                BatchSize -> 256, MaxTrainingRounds -> 10];
```

[image]

```
reconstructor = Take[trained, {NetPort["Input"], NetPort["Output"]}];
BlockRandom[Grid[{#, ImageAdd[reconstructor[#], meanImage] & /@ #} &@
   RandomSample[trainingImages, 10]], RandomSeeding -> 1234]
```

[image]

```
encoder = Take[trained, {NetPort["Input"], 1}];
testImages = Keys[testSubset];
coords = DimensionReduce[encoder[testImages], 2, Method -> "TSNE"];
labels = Values[testSubset];
ListPlot[Table[Extract[coords, Position[labels, i]], {i, 0, 4}], 
 PlotLegends -> PointLegend[96, Range[0, 4]], Axes -> None, 
 PlotStyle -> Map[ColorData[96], Range[1, 5]], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

The loss of LSTM(purple color) fall down slowly

```
Show[{lossplot1, lossplot2 /. Hue[__] -> Hue[0.75]}]
```

[image]

How to improve the result?

*PS:Using LSTM to predict digits number in MNIST got a good result even data is image instead of temporal time-series in this case*

> Using LSTM,the dimensions of *embedding vector* after LSTM is also 16,it can be think a presentation or encoder of the image.

why in the above case,same *embedding vector* size can't get a pretty good result of auto-encoder?

```
lstmnet = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
                    SequenceLastLayer[], LinearLayer[5], SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
                    "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 4]}], 
                    "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]];
trained = NetTrain[lstmnet, trainingSubset, ValidationSet -> testSubset, 
                   BatchSize -> 256, MaxTrainingRounds -> 5]
ClassifierMeasurements[trained, testSubset]["Accuracy"]
(*0.965947*)
```

[image]

Using CNN(lenet version)

```
lenet = NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[20, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2], 
                  ConvolutionLayer[50, 5], Ramp, PoolingLayer[2, 2], FlattenLayer[],
                  500, Ramp, 5, SoftmaxLayer[]}, 
                  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", Range[0, 4]}], 
                  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale"}]];
trained = NetTrain[lenet, trainingSubset, ValidationSet -> testSubset,
                   BatchSize -> 256,MaxTrainingRounds -> 5]
ClassifierMeasurements[trained, testSubset]["Accuracy"]
(*0.997081*)
```

Comment: I think that there is no way to improve the result. Because LSTM is not suitable for images. See your screenshot from Keras blog: "If you inputs are sequences, **rather than** vectors or **2D images**, then you may want to use as encoder and decoder a type of model that can capture temporal structure, such as a LSTM". Answer on the first revision of your question is the same: no way. Because your data are random. It's very hard to overfit random data. Have you tried LSTM autoencoder on your real data?

Comment: @Alexey Golyshev I tried to use LSTM to classify digits in MNIST,and the result is good, I will update the question.And I try LSTM auto-encoder in my project.The loss can't be declined too much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I compare many net structure using LSTM.

**Then finding multi-stacks LSTM will get a more accurate result.But it's not as effective as enlarge the embedding size.**

***Note:All the networks use this code as basic model,batch size 256,epochs 10***

```
net = NetGraph[{encoder, decoder, MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, 
               {1 -> 2 -> NetPort["Output"], 2 -> NetPort[3, "Input"], NetPort["Input"] -> NetPort[3, "Target"]}, 
               "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {28, 28}, "Grayscale", "MeanImage" -> meanImage}], 
               "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Image", "Grayscale"}]]
```

Baseline network:

```
encoder = NetChain[{FlattenLayer[], 100, Ramp, 50, Ramp, 16}];
decoder = NetChain[{50, Ramp, 100, Ramp, 784, ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using single LSTM(state size 16):

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
                    SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using single LSTM(state size 64):

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using double LSTM(state size 16):

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using double LSTM(state size 64):

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using triple LSTM(state size 64):

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using triple LSTM(state size 64) and DNN:

Contrary to my expectations, it didn't get a better result compare to the above net :)

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    SequenceLastLayer[], 32, ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], 16}];
decoder = NetChain[{32, ElementwiseLayer["SELU"], 64, ReplicateLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using **quadruple LSTM(state size 64)** - ***Best*** result of LSTM family.

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
                    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

[image]

Visualize the effect of auto-encoder of Bast result(using **quadruple LSTM(state size 64)**),the effect of clustering is pretty good.

[image]

[image]

Extreme Test:

**Enlarge the number of LSTM-staks is not an efficency way, it will make the net hard to train. In other words, Increasing the number of LSTM-stacks may not be effective.**

Using quadruple LSTM(state size 16):

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

Using octuple LSTM(state size 16),it is very hard to train because too many parameters.

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

[image]

Finally,Come back to this question.

We can simulate the process the auto-encoder of DNN, not only the result is not bad but also it can learn the embedding size(16) if using the structure of Best result of **quadruple LSTM(state size 64)**

```
encoder = NetChain[{ReshapeLayer[{28, 28}], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[64], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[32], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], SequenceLastLayer[]}];
decoder = NetChain[{ReplicateLayer[28], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[16], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[32], LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], 
    LongShortTermMemoryLayer[28], ReshapeLayer[{1, 28, 28}]}];
```

We can see the result is not bad.

[image]

*The loss plot refer the answer from [Adding legends when using Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127213/15961)*