# Using NetTrain with HDF5?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I have some nicely formatted training data in [HDF5 files](http://machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/data_preparation/hdf5/hdf5.html), i.e. the images and labels are serialized within the H5 file as groups and datasets.

AFAIK `NetTrain` only works in an out-of-core mode on lists of paths each wrapped in `File`.

Is there any way to get `NetTrain` to work off of the training data stored in an H5 file efficiently (with parallelized batch loading)?

**Update from comment:**

@AlexeyGolyshev suggested to use @TaliesinBeynon's undocumented answer which doesn't seem to work anymore in v11.3:

```
{input, output} = RandomReal[1, {2, 1000, 2}];
<< GeneralUtilities`;
fn = FileNameJoin[{CreateDirectory[], "test.h5"}]
ExportStructuredHDF5[fn, <|"Input" -> input, "Output" -> output|>];
NetTrain[LinearLayer["Input" -> 2, "Output" -> 2], File[fn]]
```

[image]

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146266

Comment: @AlexeyGolyshev I saw that but it stopped working for me (in v11.3)

Comment: I have no errors (even with `ValidationSet`). https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1W0n.png

Comment: You’re on Windows, maybe just it doesn’t work on macOS?

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows 10, Mathematica 11.3.0. I agree that maybe it just doesn't work on macOS. Try to write to the developers.

Comment: But even if it did work there’s no obvious way to get it to work for images

Comment: There is a way ;-) https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvVas0AkeAWi0Gyj_B994tlvWwWZ

Comment: I just force restarted Mathematica and now it's working, weird... Ok Just post your sweet example notebook and I will accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Example of how to pack images in HDF5 and train neural network**

```
SeedRandom[0];
X = Table[RandomImage[1, {32, 32}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"], 10];
Y = RandomInteger[1, 10];

enc = NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}, ColorSpace -> "RGB"}];

Export["data.h5",
 {
  "Datasets" ->
   {
    "Input" -> Flatten /@ enc@X,
    "Output" -> N@Y
    },
  "DataFormat" -> {Automatic, Automatic}
  },
 "Rules"
 ];

net = NetChain[{
   ReshapeLayer[{3, 32, 32}],
   ConvolutionLayer[32, {3, 3}],
   2,
   SoftmaxLayer[]
   },
  "Input" -> 3*32*32,
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {0, 1}}]
  ]
```

[image]

```
netT = NetTrain[net, File["data.h5"]]
```

[image]