# Custom NetEncoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I've been trying to train an RNN on some data that I pre-processed externally and saved to disk. My dataset is too large to fit in memory and is additionally varying in shape.

Looking for a way to do out-of-core training with such requirements, the closest thing I've found was [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/170468/59231), however it's not quite what I need.

So, my question is whether or not I can create custom `NetEncoder` (i.e. something I can pass into my `NetGraph`). Or if this is a feature being worked on?

Otherwise, is my only option to load subsets of my data for training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general way of doing out-of-core training is to use the 5th usage of `NetTrain` (`NetTrain[net, f]`). You can write a custom data loader/sampler `f` that reads from disk (make sure its fast enough though!).

I would also recommend this tutorial to anyone thinking of doing out-of-core training: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksLargeDatasets.html